# StackExchange.Redis high cpu usage

Tags: .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I've been pulling out my hair on this one. I have a dotnet core(3.1) service deployed in a swarm of 3 workernodes, on each node I have a web api that uses redis for various things. The redis server itself never is busy, and the cpu rarely exceeds 4%, but my web api's cpu usage is quite high (~60% average). I used dotnet trace to check what's eating my cpu and found [image]

All work seems to go to the thread pool scheduler used by StackExchange.Redis. I'm only reusing 1 ConnectionMultiplexer and stored it in a singleton as recommended. I've tried StackExchange.Redis 2.1 as well as the latest version, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Can anyone pinpoint me to what might be wrong here?

Comment: Reply by mail from @Marc Gravell: "Very hard to comment without knowledge of your workloads, but: I'm in the process of adding a pooled core that obviates the multiplexer and dedicated worker pool. Maybe this by itself will fix everything, but; I need to finish the code. The proof-of-concept worked great for this, but since this isn't my day job, it needs to wait on my availability."

Comment: it's been more than a year since you posted this but I have a similar situation now, could you please share what did you figure-out in the end? My understanding is that this happens due to the HeartBeat which executes every second, per connection. HeartBeat then, after few seconds, triggers RunWorkLoop.

Comment: So I'm moving away from StackExchange.Redis

Comment: @HaiNguyen sigh yes, which one are you moving to?

Comment: @ElgerMensonides and someone else: I did so many perfmon by dottrace and it DID tell me that hot path was in SE.Redis, but I was so wrong. I found the root cause eventually. It was not in SE.Redis so I moved back because it is way easier to use. Sorry for late replying.

Comment: @HaiNguyen could you please elaborate, what made you think u were wrong?

Comment: @ElgerMensonides After moving to ServiceStack.Redis I still encountered high CPU in my app so I thought it was not SE.Redis' fault, back to my app I filtered all noisy reports  from perfmon carefully then found the root cause. My peer had an algorithm ran into a long running loop (not infinite, but called often). After correcting it we were fine. SE.Redis' API is better at async/await. PS: I had exactly problem in your screenshot, still wonder why RunWorkLoop() took so much CPU time then I had to look in other hot paths.